# Fast NMS algorithm suppresses boxes without overlap

Tags: python, algorithm, object-detection, non-maximum-suppression

I'm testing out the [Fast NMS algorithm by Malisiewicz et al](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/16/faster-non-maximum-suppression-python/). I noticed while running through examples that in one case, if I input two particular boxes that have no overlap, with an IoU threshold below approximately 0.75, one box is suppressed anyway.

Am I misunderstanding NMS? I thought that no boxes should be dropped if there's zero overlap between them, regardless of where the IoU threshold is set.

Example:

```
import numpy as np

def non_max_suppression_fast(boxes, overlapThresh):

    # if there are no boxes, return an empty list
    if len(boxes) == 0:
        return []

    # initialize the list of picked indexes
    pick = []

    # grab the coordinates of the bounding boxes
    x1 = boxes[:,0]
    y1 = boxes[:,1]
    x2 = boxes[:,2]
    y2 = boxes[:,3]

    # compute the area of the bounding boxes and sort the bounding
    # boxes by the bottom-right y-coordinate of the bounding box
    area = (x2 - x1 + 1) * (y2 - y1 + 1)

    idxs = np.argsort(y2)

    # keep looping while some indexes still remain in the indexes
    # list
    while len(idxs) > 0:
        # grab the last index in the indexes list and add the
        # index value to the list of picked indexes
        last = len(idxs) - 1
        i = idxs[last]
        pick.append(i)

        # find the largest (x, y) coordinates for the start of
        # the bounding box and the smallest (x, y) coordinates
        # for the end of the bounding box
        xx1 = np.maximum(x1[i], x1[idxs[:last]])
        yy1 = np.maximum(y1[i], y1[idxs[:last]])
        xx2 = np.minimum(x2[i], x2[idxs[:last]])
        yy2 = np.minimum(y2[i], y2[idxs[:last]])

        # compute the width and height of the bounding box
        w = np.maximum(0, xx2 - xx1 + 1)
        h = np.maximum(0, yy2 - yy1 + 1)

        # compute the ratio of overlap
        overlap = (w * h) / area[idxs[:last]]

        # delete all indexes from the index list that have
        idxs = np.delete(idxs, np.concatenate(([last],
            np.where(overlap > overlapThresh)[0])))

    # return only the bounding boxes that were picked
    return boxes[pick]


# Two test boxes
                   #xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax
boxes = np.vstack([[0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5], 
                  [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2]])


# no box suppression
print(non_max_suppression_fast(boxes, overlapThresh=.75))

# one box is suppressed
print(non_max_suppression_fast(boxes, overlapThresh=.74))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your input test case is not legal, argument `boxes` expect boxes coordinates in absolute format, e.g. in pixel coordinates.

you can notice that when calculating area of all boxes, it is

```
area = (x2 - x1 + 1) * (y2 - y1 + 1)
```

the `+1` is an added pixel, making sure `area` is actual number of pixels the box occupies.

try this:

```
boxes = np.vstack([[3, 2, 4, 5], 
              [1, 1, 2, 2]])
```